# Slack Interactive Messages: POST request payload has an unexpected format

Tags: python, flask, slack-api

I'm getting a POST request inside a Flask app from Slack. The request is sent when a user presses on an interactive message button. According to Slack [docs](https://api.slack.com/docs/verifying-requests-from-slack) I must extract the body of the request to verify the signature. 
My computed signature doesn't match the one sent by Slack, though.
In fact, the body of the request comes as some encoded string. The string is actually an encoded dictionary instead of a query str parameters, as expected.

Here's the beginning of my view:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_visit():
    data = request.get_data()
    signature = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Signature', None)
    timestamp = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Request-Timestamp', None)
    signing_secret = b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'


    # old message, ignore
    if round(actual_time.time() - float(timestamp)) > 60 * 5:
        return
    concatenated = ("v0:%s:%s" % (timestamp, data)).encode('utf-8')
    computed_signature = 'v0=' + hmac.new(signing_secret, msg=concatenated, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    if hmac.compare_digest(computed_signature, signature):
        ...
```

I've tried to format the received data to make it look like:

`token=fdjkgjl&user_id=1234...` but I am not aware of all of the necessary parameters that have to be present in the data.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

The body of the message is following - after being URL decoded (note I've modified possibly sensitive data):

> b'payload={"type":"interactive_message","actions": 
>   [{"name":"yes_button","type":"button","value":"236"}],"callback_id":"visit_button","team":{"id":"fffff","domain":"ffff"},"channel":{"id":"ffff","name":"directmessage"},"user":{"id":"ffffff","name":"fffft"},"action_ts":"1540403943.419120","message_ts":"1541403949.000100","attachment_id":"1","token":"8LpjBuv13J7xAjhl2lEajoBU","is_app_unfurl":false,"original_message":{"text":"Test","bot_id":"DDDDDDDDD","attachments":[{"callback_id":"visit_button","text":"Register","id":1,"color":"3AA3E3","actions":[{"id":"1","name":"yes_button","text":"Yes","type":"button","value":"236","style":""}],"fallback":"Register"}],"type":"message","subtype":"bot_message","ts":"1540413949.000100"},"response_url":"https://hooks.slack.com/actions/ffffff/ffffff/tXJjx1XInaUhrikj6oEzK08e","trigger_id":"464662548327.425084163429.dda35a299eedb940ab98dbb9386b56f0"}'

Comment: Have a look at the official slack API client for python: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient.

Comment: Looks to me a bit that you are confusing header and body of the request. The header will contain the Signature, and the body will contain everything else from the request (e.g. user ID). Note that the body is a POST form with the single property `payload`. That property contains the request data as JSON array. see [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#responding_to_message_actions)

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Where exactly do you see that I am confusing them? The body does contain the payload. That's exactly what I am getting. But check this out, the body comes as something like this:
b'payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22interactive_message%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22kaynti...'

Comment: @Fian Well, the functionality I'm trying to achieve shouldn't require any libraries. It's just a regular POST request, which I should be able to handle with Python/Flask built-in functionality. Have you used the library for interactive messages?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood then. apologizes. your body is URL encoded. I am not super familiar with Python / Flask, but you should get it in plain text with `request.form.get('payload')`. [Source](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask)

Comment: Please also include your "garbled" body example in your question and how you access it

Comment: Yes, exactly. I SHOULD, but I don't. Yes, my body is URL encoded and even after I decode it, it looks like a JSON. I edited the post to include the garbled message URL decoded already.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I've also included how I'm accessing it, with the line:
```data = request.get_data()```

Comment: Cool. Now you just need JSON decode the payload string and you should have it. Have you also tried `request.form.get('payload')` ??

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Nope, I wouldn't have asked here if it would have been so simple. The message should come in the format: token=dfgkfdg&...
And I am not sure of all the parameters and format it should include. Check the source you've linked yourself. There it's shown the correct format. I get it in a weird JSON format instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the issue wasn't related to how Slack sends me the message. It was about misunderstanding which data comes as bytes and which data is unicode. The culprit was string formatting in my case - the line `concatenated = ("v0:%s:%s" % (timestamp, data)).encode('utf-8')` should have been `concatenated = (b"v0:%b:%b" % (timestamp.encode("utf-8"), data))`. Data is already bytes, timestamp meanwhile is unicode.
Cannot believe I've banged my head on this for hours -_-

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_visit():
    data = request.get_data()
    signature = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Signature', None)
    timestamp = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Request-Timestamp', None)
    signing_secret = b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    # old message, ignore
    if round(actual_time.time() - float(timestamp)) > 60 * 5:
        return
    concatenated = (b"v0:%b:%b" % (timestamp.encode("utf-8"), data))
    computed_signature = 'v0=' + hmac.new(signing_secret, msg=concatenated, 
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    if hmac.compare_digest(computed_signature, signature):
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting the "garbled" data is that you are using `request.get_data()`. That method will return the **raw** data of a request, but not do any decoding for you.

Much more convenient is to use `request.form.get('payload')`, which will directly give you the JSON string of the request object. You can then convert that into a dict object with `json.loads()` to process it further in your app.

Note that the format you received is the correct format for interactive messages. You will not get a query string (e.g. "token=abc;user_id?def...") as you suggested (like for slash command requests). Interactive message request will always contain the request as JSON string in a payload form property. See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#responding_to_message_actions) for reference.

Here is a simple working example, which will reply a greeting to the user that pressed the button. It will work directly with Slack, but I recommend using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test it.

```
#app.py

from flask import Flask, request #import main Flask class and request object
import json

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_visit():
    slack_req = json.loads(request.form.get('payload'))
    response = '{"text": "Hi, <@' + slack_req["user"]["id"] + '>"}'
    return response, 200, {'content-type': 'application/json'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000) #run app in debug mode on port 5000
```

Comment: OK, maybe I wasn't clear when I posted that question. I think you misunderstand what I am asking. 
This is how the raw body (that's the one I actually need) should look like:
```token=xyzz0WbapA4vBCDEFasx0q6G&team_id=T1DC2JH3J&team_domain=testteamnow&channel_id=G8PSS9T3V&channel_name=foobar&user_id=U2CERLKJA&user_name=roadrunner&command=%2Fwebhook-collect&text=&response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2Fcommands%2FT1DC2JH3J%2F397700885554%2F96rGlfmibIGlgcZRskXaIFfN&trigger_id=398738663015.47445629121.803a0bc887a14d10d2c447fce8b6703c```. 
As a query string, not a dictionary/JSON.

Comment: As I said: that is a query string as you would get from a slash command request. But you don't get it from an interactive action request. If you need that particular format you will need to convert it manually from JSON object to flat query string. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: In other words: it seams that your premise is wrong. You are looking to get a query string from an interactive action request. But that is not what Slack will send you. Slack will send you a JSON string in an form property. Please double check the documentation I linked you and you will see I am correct. Here is it: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#responding_to_message_actions

Comment: OK, thanks for that! However, the signature I am computing from the garbled message doesn't correspond to the one sent by Slack. That's why I thought that the format is wrong.
Btw, check this part: https://api.slack.com/docs/verifying-requests-from-slack#known_issues_and_gotchas
Here it's mentioned I should specifically get the raw data and compute the signature from it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
from urllib import parse

parsed_text = parse.unquote('your bytes text here')
```